# Network Error in React-Native with Expo CLI

Tags: android, react-native, axios, fetch, expo

I'm getting the following error whenever I try to make a request to API with Axios or fetch. I'm using expo 40.0.0 and react-native SDK 40.0.0. Everything is perfect I have triple-checked. API get me the response whenever I tried to test through Post-man. I think there is something wrong with the Android native code as I'm testing with EXPO on android. Please help me out I have tried everything and I'm new to react-native. I tried to make the request to outside API and my own API(Running on my machine) too but getting the same errot.

```
Request failed with status code 400
at node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:15:17 in createError
at node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:16:9 in settle
at node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:53:6 in handleLoad
at node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent      
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:592:4 in setReadyState
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue   
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Comment: Can we see the code of your fetch ?

Comment: `const apiSearch = async()=>{
 try{
 const res  = await  yelp.get('/status',{
 params : {
 limit : 50,
 search,
 location : 'san jose' }
                    })
        console.log(res)
                    }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    }`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the fetch/Axios. I have tested it by putting the network call into a separate file and then run that file through the node. It works perfectly but when I call it through my android it throws an error. As long as I guess the last line of the error is where something getting wrong in the native code.

Comment: @docmurloc Thanks alot bro, There was a mistake in my base url , it was a typo. just spend 3 days on it. what a stupid i'm. :-(